# Why is the start of the year in Moment.js December 31?

Tags: momentjs

I've been banging my head against the keyboard for about a day now trying to figure out this time variance with momentjs.

I have an API endpoint that sets the time the request came in by calling

`var now = moment().valueOf();`

Then, it finds the beginning of the year by simply calling

`moment(now).startOf('year');`

After about 48 hours of seeding our DB with test data on a run, I noticed that the timestamp set in the database is December 31, 2015 (1451624400000).

When I run the program locally, the timestamp is January 1, 2016 (1451635200000).

When I log into our servers, create a test script to find the variance, and log the output, the timestamp is January 1, 2016.

Nothing is touching the time except for this one method in the api.

Is there some reason why momentjs would think the start of the year is December 31, 2015? If so, how do I change it? Haven't been able to find any help on this so far, and the moment.js docs explicitly say the start of the year is January 1 of the year.

Comment: Could it be a timezone thing? What is the time of day that goes with that 31st of December?

Comment: If you save the entire timestamp, not just the date, please post samples, this is usually due to server's time difference from UTC

Comment: @AndrewMorton, the time attached to it is Thu Dec 31 2015 21:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)

Comment: The main confusion here is the fact that the time is set with moment.js on the server. We have a piece of hardware that has sent 4k requests to the server and all of them were tagged with the beginning of the year being December 31. When I send a request with postman, the beginning of the year is January 1. When I write a test script on the server, it's also January 1. The client has no say in the time, the time is created when the request is received on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been around for quite sometime.

I faced similar issue and the solution to this is formatting the result.

`var startOfThisYear = moment().startOf('year').format();`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, all.

It *was* a timezone issue, after all. I was overlooking a few things and had myself convinced I was testing consistently.

I had to configure the timezone on our Ubuntu machines with

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

We will be setting up NTP servers in addition for future prevention of such a variance.